# angular2 - can't connect to API "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2. I am trying to implement an authentication to an app with a username and password login credentials but I always get a "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

[image: No access allow control origin]

below is my code:

```
  onSubmit() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://local.press.hosting:8080');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  this.http.post('http://staging.press.hosting:9000/api/v1/adminLogin', JSON.stringify({"username":this.username,"password":this.password}),{headers:headers})
        .subscribe((res)=>{
            console.log(res)
        });
  }
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header by your server, not request header. You need to set on server side. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: @LukeHutton you should post that as an answer instead of a comment, it's the correct answer

Comment: why did you cancel my edit? I changed the AngularJS tag with Angular. Check here:  http://angularjs.blogspot.nl/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header set by your server code. In this case, the api hosted at `staging.press.hosting:9000`. It is not a request header needed to be set by the client.

You need to set this response header in your api code.

See this detailed answer for more information as it shouldn't be needed to repeat here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/368552